# 20% turnover in our company in half a year. Is that an outlier?

Tags: employees

Our company had lots of new hires last year. Number of employees went up to almost 400. 
I have just found out in our internal system that over 80 people left in the last 6 months. That makes a 20% turnover, 40% annualized if this continues, if I understand it well.

Seems like a lot to me, I think big companies proud themselves with having their employee turnover numbers in the scale of several percent.

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: How many people did you hire in the last year? If you went from 100 or 200 to 400, I suspect you don't have a problem - there's going to be lots of fallout with new hires, and if you've been on a hiring binge, you've got lots of new hires.

Comment: This probably varies greatly by industry and country. It also likely varies by internal turnover rates (ie people taking new positions internally).

Comment: What kind of company? In what country? Any relevant info as to the general economic situation in the area?

Comment: This is probably just a hire-fast, fire-fast company. They try lots of people and fire at the first sign of trouble, so it's just their philosophy. They also tend to be high-stress, so people will leave on top of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on the country, the business and other factors. A 40% turnover translates into an average tenure of two and a half years. Is that long or short for your conditions?

People in Europe will stay longer at their jobs than in the US. Average tenure in the retail business at the associate level in the US can be as low as 6 months, so 40% turnover will be very low for US retailers at this hierarchy level.

If I were in a business with a critical need for experienced people with a certain tenure, I would be concerned at such a figure, but it really depends.

Comment: I would add the the rate of change of the turn over is also very important. If the company previously had a low turnover then it starts growing, its usually a good sign of problems.